# Retrieve the file download triggered by a python request

Tags: python, urllib2

I want to capture a file that is downloaded when a certain url is passed in python. The problem is that the downloaded file is NOT returned by the server. The file gets downloaded when I pass the same url in a browser, but not when I do so via `urllib2.urlopen()`. Is there a way to capture this seemingly triggered side effect in python ? This is what I have so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib
import urllib2
import re
import sys
import os

def main(sem_id):
    url = '<url>'
    for i in range(1,71):
        if i < 10:
            rollNo = '<roll_number>0%s'%i
        else:
            rollNo = '<roll_number>%s'%i

        values = { 'id':sem_id, 'regno':rollNo, 'sum':100, 'sessionok':'yes' }
        data = urllib.urlencode(values)
        url = url + '?' + data
        req = urllib2.Request(url)
        req.add_header('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux i686)')

        response = urllib2.urlopen(req,timeout=100)

        result = response.read()


        with open('%s.pdf'%rollNo,'w') as f:
            f.write(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert len(sys.argv) == 2
    sem_id = sys.argv[1]
    main(sem_id)
```

Comment: Make sure to provide all request headers the browser sends (you can inspect them in the browser’s dev tools). Once it works from Python, you can start removing some headers until you find out which combination is necessary for the server to respond to you.

Comment: @poke I added all the headers the browser sends, but all I got in response was a gzipped form of the same html.

Answer (score 0):

We can't really diagnose this if you don't tell us what it *does* return. If you need any sort of login to access it, it won't work because Python doesn't have your browser cookies. Python also won't automatically follow some types of redirects and anything Javascript-dependant is right out of the question. Those would be the first things to check for.

Comment: It returns the html of the page to which the browser redirects to after the download starts. The downloaded file is a pdf.

Comment: I surpassed all the login and javascript that was there in the page. The url I am sending the final url sent.

Comment: Does that page start the download with JavaScript? Disable scripting in your browser and see if it still downloads. If not, it's JavaScript driven. If that's the case, you're going to have to parse the page somewhat to find and extract the appropriate URL.

Comment: When I disabled javascript, the file did not download. Apparently the initial request returns a cookie and the location of the file on the server(which is created ONLY on the initial request and is removed after download) and it is a SECOND request that actually downloads the file.